# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in vue-js/babylon.js project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, syntax-error, babylonjs

I want to use `babylon-js` in a `vuejs-website`. I created a scene and used the "Asset"-tag to show my 3D-model in the scene.

when running my project on a localhost i get the error

> `"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".`

I tried using an other 3D-model (i.e.: "https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/scenes/skull.babylon") to load in the screen this error doesn't show up. I searched for this error in but wasn't able to find a working solution. 
I have no idea how to fix this error and I'd be thankful for any suggestions.

```
Code: 
    <Scene id="scene">
            <Asset src="~@/assets/untitled.babylon" class="asset"></Asset>
    </Scene>
```

Edited:

[This is the code causing the error: the babylonFileLoader tries to parse data into JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHfxm.png)

Comment: Could you post the code that's actually generating this error?
It looks like it's attempting to load the XML `<Scene>` data you just posted as JSON, which wont work

Comment: Hi Samuel, how does untitled.babylon look like?

Comment: it expects a JSON, the message is pretty clear